# python: replace exact match using a variable

Tags: python, regex

Program reads a text file and replaces a matched word based on a variable. The problem is that non-exact matches are being replaced. So if I'm replacing "the" with "da" the word "then" becomes "dan"

```
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
 if os.path.isfile(fn):
    if fn.endswith(".txt"):

        s = open(fn).read()

        for i in skills:
            link = skills[i]        

            s = s.replace(i, "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" %(link,i), 1)

        print "%s updated" %fn

        f = open(fn, 'w')
        f.write(s)
        f.close()
```

The issue is at `s = s.replace(i, "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" %(link,i), 1)` where the first argument in s.replace() is the variable containing the string I want to match for.

I've tried using word boundaries `s = s.replace(r'\b'+i+r'\b', "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" %(link,i), 1)`

and formatting the value at `i` into a new variable: `regex = r'\b' + i + r'\b'` and using `regex` as the first argument in `s.replace` but it doesn't work.

Note. `skills` is a dictionary containing word/link pairs

Comment: Can you provide examples of input and output strings and also demonstrating the actual problem. We dont have your files, so we dont know what is your input and expected output from the `replace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `s` is a **string**, it won't support **regular expression** operations.

To use regular expressions on your strings, you need to do that explicitly.

So put at the start of your code

```
import re
```

and where you now use

```
s = s.replace(i, "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" %(link,i), 1)
```

use, instead,

```
s = re.sub(r'\b'+i+r'\b', '<a href="%s">%s</a>'%(link,i), s, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `string` is the contents of your read file:

```
string = string.replace('the ', 'da ') # space ensures then isn't replaced
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function when using regex to match the characters you want to replace. `string.replace` function won't take regex as an argument.